# Using both GCM push Notification service and Parse push notification service in android app

Tags: parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I am using GCM push notification service in my android app. Now, I have to Use both parse and GCM push notification in my android app. But, I am not getting notification from both GCM and Parse (may be due to conflict). I can reach both GCM and Parse individually but never together, My implementation looks this way;

I have registered Receivers for both GCM and Parse as fallows;

The following receiver is for GCM;

```
<receiver
android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter>
    <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

    <category android:name="com.example.test" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The receiver and service for Parse is as fallows;

```
<service android:name="com.parse.PushService"></service>

<receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
android:exported="false">
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
<intent-filter android:priority="0">
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
    <category android:name="com.example.test" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I have called Parse Initialization in Application class as;

```
Parse.setLogLevel(Parse.LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE);
Parse.initialize(this, "APPLICATION_ID", "CLIENT_KEY");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

I have implemented GCMIntentService for GCM as fallows;

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";
    GCMManager gcmManager;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        super(Config.SENDER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device registered
     */
    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        gcmManager = new GCMManager(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        displayMessage(context, "Your device registred with GCM");
        ServerUtilities.register(context, registrationId);
        gcmManager.saveGcmRegistrationId(registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on device un registred
     */
    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        displayMessage(context, getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        ServerUtilities.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    /**
     * Method called on Receiving a new message
     */
    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        // displayMessage(context, message);

        try {
            String message = intent.getExtras().getString(Constant.TAG_MESSAGE);
            String id = intent.getExtras().getString(Constant.TAG_ID);
            String title = intent.getExtras().getString(Constant.TAG_TITLE);
            String type = intent.getExtras().getString(Constant.TAG_NOTIFICATION_TYPE);

            Log.e("Message : ", message);
            Log.e("Title : ", title);
            Log.e("ID : ", id);
            Log.e("Type : ", type);

            // notifies user
            generateNotification(context, message, title, id, type);
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Parse push notification basically use the GCM push notification, so I dont think you can use them at the same time. Just pick up one.

Comment: Could you add your InstanceID getToken code to the question?

Comment: @ArthurThompson: where should i use InstanceID getToken code and if added what will happen.

Comment: I may be mistaken, I thought you were using both Parse and GCM, but I think you may be just using Parse which in turn uses GCM.

Comment: Both parse and GCM works, but their is delay in Parse notification or sometimes message not delivered.

Comment: Both parse and GCM works, what i did i used default SENDER_ID="1076345567071" for GCM registration which is by default used by parse. But their is delay in Parse notification or sometimes message not delivered...testing is time consuming due to intermittent nature of message delivery.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610972/two-push-notification-services-in-android/34709032#34709032. I suggested a solution that may suit your needs.