# Two Push Notification services in android

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I have integrated Parse SDK with my project already and implemented Parse Push Notification and its working perfectly.
But the Problem is:
When I integrate another Push Service in my project, the parse Push Stops working?

**Note:**

1.Parse uses its own push service.

2.The new Push I tried to use use GCM push service.

Is there any clash between them or is there any way we can manage both?

Comment: afaik Parse also uses GCM, just wraps around it, also, this question depends heavily on your signing configs, server keys, and gcm project setup, you will have to describe your setup at the very least

Comment: Send JSON from cloud code and catch that JSON and play with it in the receiver.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use two Gcm clients with Gcm broadcast receiver in your own project - the last broadcast receiver registered will get the msgs coming from the Gcm servers. in other words - there will always be only one broadcast receiver that will get these msgs . In your case - the second service you added is receiving the Gcm msgs because it was registered last, probably handling it's own msgs and discarding the others.

Had a similar similar problem in my app where I used a lib that used Gcm msgs and my app was using Gcm as well. after adding the services and broadcast receivers in the app's manifest - the lib stopped receiving Gcm msgs.

The solution is not elegant - In the onReceive function of the broadcast receiver - I distinguished between Gcm msgs targeting my app and those targeting the lib in my broadcast receiver , handled the ones for my app as they should and for the ones targeting the lib - I start a new intent with the extras data , which triggered the lib's broadcast receiver. I could take this approach because I control the code for both the app and lib.

Hope this helps.